# jquery dialog tabindex for buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've a `dialog box` with two buttons on it using `jQuery UI`.

Inside of the dialog there are some form elements which I can switch by using the TAB-key. Now it isn't possible to access the "Yes" Button with the TAB-key. Seams there is no `TabIndex`.

How can I make this possible?

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 250,
    width: 420,
    zIndex: 100,
    stack: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            doSomthing();
        },
        "No": function () {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI are you using? Works fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/puCx8/

Comment: a button doesn't need a tabindex to receive focus. Seems works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y3u9/

Answer (score 2):

Change the buttons parameter to use jQuery.ui's array specification, which allows setting things like the ID and TabIndex of a button, among any other supported attribute that the button widget supports.

```
buttons: [
        {
            text: "Yes",
            click: function() { doSomething(); },
            tabindex: 0
        },
        {
            text: "No",
            click: function() { $(this).dialog("close") },
            tabindex: -1, //You can disable tabbing by setting it -1
            class: 'other-class-name',
            id: 'IDofButton'
        }
]
```

Just a heads up on jQuery.ui versions - Version 1.10 supports the full button subset - Previous iterations of jQuery.ui support a smaller subset - YMMV - My approach in the past was to try adding elements and seeing how it was parsed - for example, in legacy versions, the class parameter may be class**es** and some of the other parameters may be ignored.